# How to set Environment Variable for NLTK in Mac?

Tags: python, macos, nltk

I recently downloaded nltk_data in Macintosh HD 2 (Renamed "External") since my main HD is out of memory, can someone help me in setting environment variables for the same? I tried the following in my .bash_profile however it just runs temporarily till bash runs, I need to make the change permanent:

```
PATH="$/Volumes/External/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting environment variables on OS X is a bit tricky, and it's a moving target: Stackoverflow is full of good solutions that no longer work.

If your goal is to use the nltk from programs or applications that you launch from Terminal, then it's pretty straightforward; in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`, set and export the required variables.

- If you have trouble launching the right Python or `idle` executable, add the directory that contains them to your `PATH` variable pretty much as you show in your question. (But the first `$` you show is a mistake: This path is not a shell variable).

  ```
  export PATH="/Volumes/External/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- To allow the nltk to find the corpora and resources you downloaded with `nltk.download()`, set the `NLTK_DATA` variable. E.g.,

  ```
  export NLTK_DATA=/Volumes/External/nltk_data
  ```

It looks like your question was answered by the second bullet, but I give both since it's not always clear (to new users) which one is relevant.

Be aware that applications you launch from the Launchpad (e.g., the Anaconda launcher) will not be able to see variables you set in this way. That is a more complicated problem to solve, as mentioned above, and as far as I know there is no solution that will work for all applications in recent OS X versions. Just launch your python application or IDE from the command line (by typing `idle`, `subl` etc. at the bash prompt), and you'll be all right.

Comment: You are a life saver!

Comment: @alexis, is there a way to start deleting answers that no longer work? I've tried for some questions to mass-edit them with "Warnings" in bold, esp. when the issue re-surfaced and people use the SO answers that don't work any longer than escalate the problem to github repos and spamming the same problem on different issues =(

Comment: @alvas I don't know what stackoverflow practices say about this; maybe you should ask on meta. But note that "no longer" is relative to the OS X version you're running, and there are still plenty of people running Yosemite or Mountain Lion or what have you. So I think the ideal solution would be to clearly specify on which OS versions a solution works on, and on which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to get access to NLTK taggers and dicts?
There is a way to extend NLTK path (it is a simple list):

```
import nltk
nltk.path.append('/home/to/some_path/nltk_data/')
```

Comment: But this i need to do every time in my python editor right?

Comment: Also you can set NLTK_DATA environment variable: `export NLTK_DATA=/path/to/nltk_data`.

Comment: Surprisingly it just started working @dmitry, thanks!